# Does there exist a ring containing $k \times k$ that is algebraically closed with respect to $k[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. We know that there exists a field $\bar{k}$ that is an algebraic closure of $k$ with respect to the polynomial ring $k[x]$.  But does there exist a ring containing $k^2$ in which all $f \in k[x, y]$ have at least one root?  I know that it must contain an isomorphic copy of $\bar{k}^2$ since for instance $f(x, 0)$ is a single-variable poly and we need a root for *it*.

Comment: Can you make your title agree with your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\bar{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$, then any non-constant polynomial $P$ in $k[x,y]$ has a root in $\bar{k}^2$. This is an easy consequence of the much stronger Nullstellensatz but it can also be seen directly.

Assume that there exists a $y$ in $\bar{k}$ such that $Q_y: x \mapsto P(x,y)$ is a non-constant polynomial. Then you have a root $x_0$ for $Q_y$ in $\bar{k}$ and $(x,y)$ is a root of $P$. So the only problem is when all $Q_y$ are constant, that is when $P$ is a polynomial in $y$ only. Then you have a root, again by the standard result in one-variable, as soon as $P$ is not constant.

Edit : The end of the proof might not be clear; one can say it otherwise. If $P$ is not constant as a function on $\bar{k}^2$, then there exists at least one $x$ or one $y$ such that $P(x,\bullet)$ or $P(\bullet,y)$ is non-constant as a function in $\bar{k}$. Then the result is clear.

Comment: How do you prove that if $Q_y$ are all constant then $P$ is a polynomial in $y$ only without Nullstellensatz? You need at the very least to use the fact that the field is infinite, as there are nonconstant polynomials which evaluate as constant functions over finite fields. In any case, I don't think it's sufficiently trivial as to be left unexplained to someone not familiar with Nullstellensatz.

Comment: I have edited my proof.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot more convincing. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x, y, z) = 0$ we can substitute in any $(y,z) \in k \times k$ and solve for $x$.  Thus $f$ has a solution in $\bar{k} \times k \times k$.

So the algebraic closure of $k^3$ is just $\bar{k}^3$.

Comment: Not any $(y,z)$, but rather one for which the substituted polynomial is non-constant.